# CoppeliaSim ZMQ Remote API Problem with Java

Tags: java, zeromq, remote-access, robotics

I am trying to control CoppeliaSim remotely using the ZMQ Remote API for Java, with: https://github.com/CoppeliaRobotics/zmq ... ree/master

But I am facing many problems. If someone can help me to solve the problems to use the Java client form their GitHub. Or maybe find another solution, look for a turn around.

1. For the CoppeliaSim Stubs generator: https://github.com/CoppeliaRobotics/inc ... /README.md.
   I do not know what to do in Usage->CMake. Where can I find the CMake they re talking about? Where should I put that CMake? I am supposed to add the lines of the Read Me into the CMake?
   Besides installing the dependencies and doing the things with the CMake, should I do something else for the CoppeliaSim Stubs generator?
2. For the ZeroMQ plugin for CoppeliaSim: https://github.com/CoppeliaRobotics/simZMQ
   I am having problems to run the commands, specifically. cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release. The error says there is not cmake command. I assume I have to install something in my computer. Could you tell me what should I install or if the solution for that is something else?
3. I am also troubled with the Java client: https://github.com/CoppeliaRobotics/zmq ... ients/java
   The class Example.java relies on the classes RemoteAPIObjects.java and RemoteAPIClient.java. However those classes are problematic. RemoteAPIClient.java calls RemoteAPIObjects.java, but RemoteAPIObjects.java has a strange wrapper in Python that does not seem to works. And RemoteAPIObjects.java calls RemoteAPIClient.java, so it is a situation where 2 classes that are not working rely on each other. Besides, Example.java calls a method .sim() from RemoteAPIObjects(), but that method does not exist.
4. In this ZeroMQ Remote API manual for CoppeliaSim: https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/
   There is no Java client. So I do not know if actually is possible to generate a functional client for Java or not.
5. In all of the methods of this Regular API Reference: https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/
   For all the methods, there is an explanation for C/C++, Lua and Python, but not for Java. So I do not know if actually that Regular API is available for Java or not.

Can someone help my to solve those problems: 1. how to set up the CoppeliaSim Stubs generator, 2. how to run all the ZMQ Plugin commands, 3. how to fix the code of the Java client from the repository, 4. how to generate a Java client according to the manual and 5. to know if the Regular API functions are available for Java or not, and if so, how to call them?

Or tell me if there is any other way to control remotely CoppeliaSim with Java, that already works? If there is no other pure Java solution, I can also switch or make a wrapping with C++ or Python. In any case, I would really appreciate if you could add a functional code to your answer for me to understand better.#

Thank you.